# Ruby : How to add values in avariable to array and delete duplicates in it?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am new to ruby. i have a database hosted localy in my lap. i am selecting some rows from DB and extracting some elements using regx . i have stored the values that i have iterated through the DB query and stored it in a variable called "ref". i need to push all that values comes to "ref" to an array and delete the duplicates from it.

Helps would be appreciated.

attching the code that im using,

```
my = Mysql.new('localhost', 'root', '', 'videos') 

list = my.query('select * from offline_renditions where secure_url LIKE "http://abcd.testing.com/movies/%" and name != "tiny"')

list.each_hash do |a| 
  ref = a['secure_url'].match(/^http:\/\/data.myDB.com\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)/)[2]
end
```

Comment: use a set instead of an array http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Comment: Does **duplicate** mean several items in the list with same `secure_url`?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your database structure and your specific business logic, you probably have two options:

1. Filter duplicates at database level, using the SQL [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) statement. This is generally the preferred path as you will reduce the amount of data transferred from the database to your system and databases are generally quite efficient at filtering duplicates
2. Filter duplicates at code level. In Ruby you can use a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) instead of an Array and it will take care of removing duplicates automatically.